# Binding ObservableCollection<Tuple<Object, List<Object>>> to DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an ObservableCollection with a Tuple and want to bind it to my DataGrid. This is the ObservableCollection:

```
ObservableCollection<Tuple<NetworkItem, List<NetworkItem>>> ListNetworkItems = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<NetworkItem, List<NetworkItem>>>();
```

And here is my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NetworkDataGrid" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListNetworkItems}" >

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sender">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item1.Device.Name, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Receiver">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.Device.Name, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

The problem is, how can I bind the second item in my ObservableCollection? This is a list of several devices which belows to the item1 in the ObservableCollection. My DataGrid should look like:

```
Sender      Receiver
Device 1    Device 2
            Device 3
            Device 5
Device 2    Device 1
Device 3    Device 2
            Device 4
```

Comment: Try putting an `ItemsControl` in the DataTemplate for the Receiver column, and binding `Item2` to the `ItemsSource` property of that control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another list control of some kind in the cells in column 2 to display your sub-list.

Something like this should work:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Receiver">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Item2}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Device.Name, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This will create an `ItemsControl` in every cell in your Receiver column to hold the list of items within the sub-list.